# Key Bindings as Alternative to KeyEvent still nonfunctional

Tags: java, swing, binding, key-bindings

Having tried KeyEvents it was recommended that I switch to Key Bindings to activate certain events by the pushing of the arrow keys while one is in a TextArea

```
                        area.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
                    .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("VK_UP"), 
                            "doEnterAction");
                    area.getActionMap().put("doEnterAction", new AbstractAction(){
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                            System.out.println("Event Handled");
                            oneRay[pick][0] = ("");
                             if(i>=4){
                                 i=0;
                                 area.setText("");
                             }
                            caller();
                        }
                    });

                    area.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
                    .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("VK_DOWN"), 
                            "doEnterAction");
                    area.getActionMap().put("doEnterAction", new AbstractAction(){
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                            System.out.println("Event 2 Handled");
                            area.append("\n"+oneRay[pick][1]);
                             buton1.setEnabled(true);
                             buton2.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });

                    area.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
                    .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("VK_RIGHT"), 
                            "doEnterAction");
                    area.getActionMap().put("doEnterAction", new AbstractAction(){
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                             if(i>=4){
                                 i=0;
                                 area.setText("");
                             }
                             caller();
                        }
```

This code covers three different Key Bindings, but none work, whether I press up down left right the cursor just moves in that direction in the TextArea.
What have I done wrong this time. Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> whether I press up down left right the cursor just moves in that direction in the TextArea.

You are building the KeyStroke incorrectly. You should not be including the "VK_" in the Keystroke. So basically nothing is being added to the InputMap.

Also your code is updating the InputMap and ActionMap with a new identifier. I find is easier to just replace the Action in the ActionMap. See [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a list of all the default Actions as well as the basic code for `replacing` the default Action (this is a different link than you got in your last posting).

Finally, in your other posting you suggested that you want to invoke the Action of a button. Well then your code should be creating an Action that can be used by the button and the Key Bindings. You create an Action the same way you create an ActionListener except you extend AbstractAction instead of implementing ActionListener.

Comment: Thank you! I never considered that it would be necessary to replace the existing function, I expected some magic - thanks again. (I will probably have another question soon though...)

Comment: @WilliamBrun, sorry my original comment was wrong, your basic code was correct, the problem was that you didn't built the KeyStroke properly, so the original Action was still being invoked. However your original code was also trying to update the InputMap and ActionMap, when you really only need to update the ActionMap with a new Action. That is what I meant when I suggested that you need to replace the Action. You don't need to make any changes to the InputMap unless you are adding and Action for a KeyStroke that does not exist in the InputMap.

Comment: Hey! That's great. I followed the source you sent me and skipped a few things and now the program works, and my assumptions regarding what could be skipped are now validated by you. Thanks.